# Error while executing git add command

Tags: asp.net, git

I have been using git for last couple of months in my asp.net application and it works perfectly fine.
Today I got an error while executing command:

```
git add *

Error:
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Source Code/Bin/itextsharp.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

error: readlink("Source Code/aspnet_client"): Function not implemented
error: unable to index file Source Code/aspnet_client
fatal: adding files failed
```

Comment: First of all try: `git add .` no atricks

Comment: @CodeWizard Already tried this one but getting the same error.

Comment: It should not make a difference, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to add links. Git has problems with adding symlinks on Window.

There is not much you can do with is rather then commiting in unix machine or try from git bash instead of the cmd.

Comment: I have tried it with git bash but problem is not solved.